# Limit number of dynamically added Table Rows using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, clone, rows

I am dynamically inserting a row into a table with JQuery using clone.

```
$('#Clone').click(function() {

    //put jquery this context into a var
    var $btn = $(this).parent();

    //use .closest() to navigate from the buttno to the closest row and clone it
    //use clone(true) to pass events to cloned item

    var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone(true).insertAfter($btn);  

});
```

The end user will control the insertion of new rows.  I need to limit the number of new rows to 5.  Is there a way to do this with a cookie or some other method (array). I could have multiple tables with there own unique id so it needs to work with multiple tables on the page.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always simply use a variable for each table to track the number of added rows.

Or another alternative would be to use jQuery's data() method which allows you to store data in a dom element directly. The click event would find its table, and update the table's data() each time a row is added, and prevent further additions when it reaches the maximum.

**EDIT:** Corrected code with check to see if theCount is undefined, and to remove a mis-placed parentheses.

```
$('#Clone').click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this).parent();
    if($btn.closest('table').data('theCount') == undefined) {
        $btn.closest('table').data('theCount', 0)
    }
    var currentCount = $btn.closest('table').data('theCount');

    if(currentCount < 5) {
        $btn.closest('tr').clone(true).insertAfter($btn);
        $btn.closest('table').data('theCount', currentCount + 1);
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: I like the JQuery data method; however the click does not insert a new row.  The currentCount is raising an undefiend error.  Could it be $(btn)?

Comment: @Rob - I've updated the code to add an if statement to check whether the data element 'theCount' had been defined (and to initialize it to 0 if not). I also had typed $(btn) in one place instead of $btn.

Should work now.

Comment: I have a textbox which is validated with jquery.validate plugin.  The textbox in the original row is validated but the cloned row is not?  Do you know how I can get the plugin to work on the cloned textbox or other inputs?

Comment: @Rob - I'm not too familiar with the validate plugin. Probably best to start a new question and ask why cloned form elements aren't getting validated.

Answer (score 1):

How about a variable?

```
function addClick(identifier, max){
  var i = 0;
  $(identifier).click(function() {
    if (i < max){
       //add row
       i++;
    } 
  }
}
addClick("#Clone", 5);
```

Alternatively, you could also set a different class on the user-added ones and then just count them inside your add function.

Answer (score 0):

You could just count the number of elements returned.

```
function countRows() {
  return $("#table-id tr").length + $("#table2-id tr").length; // etc, for all table ID's.
}
```

Or, you could add a special class to the user-added rows.

```
function countRows() {
  return $("tr.new").length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the data attribute on the table

```
   var i = $('#tableID').data('userAddedRows');//of course you need to check there is a value and such
   i++;
   $('#tableID').data('userAddedRows',i);
```

Then just check to make sure the i is less than the amount allowed

Comment: Same problem I am getting with Patrick's snippet.  i is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance but I found a JQuery Plugin that does the trick.  It is here...

http://cloudgen.w0ng.hk/jquery/table.addrow.php